# Worlds. My first ever riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> I say plenty but never with sound;
> Free to say anything, yet always bound.
>
> I like to be kindled but never kindling.
> I'm always turned yet the same way round.
>
> Born from a tree, but not in the ground,
> Small, yet inside whole worlds are found.

It's the first time I've written a riddle. I worry that it's too easy, but then riddles are much more obvious if you know the answer. Really I've no idea of how easy or hard it is, but hopefully it gives a few moments of entertainment nevertheless.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I say plenty but never with sound;

> Printed or written text says a lot about the topic

Free to say anything, yet always bound.

> A book is always bound and the author can write anything he/she wishes

I like to be kindled but never kindling.

> A book can be stored in a softcopy format on e-bookreader device such as "Kindle", Book will not like if you put it on fire but it desires your care, you must handle it carefully

I'm always turned yet the same way round.

> we turn the pages of a book one by one direction

Born from a tree, but not in the ground, Small, yet inside whole worlds are found.

> Paper is made from tree

Answer:

> I am a Book

Comment: Nice. I meant something else by "kindled". Can you think why it might like to be "kindled"?

Comment: @enoughreptocomment, o i c...you mean a softcopy on e-reader device, cool...

Comment: I'm not sure books necessarily like to be 'kindled'.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be

> a book

I say plenty but never with sound;

> You access the contents of a book through your eyes, not your ears

Free to say anything, yet always bound.

> Freedom of writing; books are bound

I like to be kindled but never kindling.
I'm always turned yet the same way round.

> Since the book is written left to right (resp right to left),
>  there is only one good way of holding it.

Born from a tree, but not in the ground,
Small, yet inside whole worlds are found.

> Books are made of paper, paper is made of wood,  etc

Comment: i am just typing the answer and see your post :(

Comment: @Vikram , same here.

Comment: Nice. What about being kindled vs kindling?

Comment: I'm surprised both answers have missed the reference to the Amazon Kindle.

Answer (score 7):

Surely this is rather

> Pages

I say plenty but never with sound;

> Pages of a book will say a lot but you read with your eyes

Free to say anything, yet always bound.

> Bound within a book

I like to be kindled but never kindling.

> Nice reference to the Amazon Kindle, which displays a page at a time. Most books would be too large to be kindling, whereas pages would be excellent.

I'm always turned yet the same way round.

> You turn the pages of a book. A book is never turned, and they are not always written in the same way, Japanese books write back to front, and other languages write vertically.

Born from a tree, but not in the ground, Small, yet inside whole worlds are found.

> Common quote - In the pages of this book you will find... Perhaps this line lends itself more to the answer as a book but it is valid in either case.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but I can't disagree with your reasoning. +1