# My body is pale, though I never fear. I might share a tale, perhaps insincere

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I speak without a voice, where you can see without an eye. 
>  A heart without a beat, I hold, can make you laugh and cry. 
>  I turn before I twist, but cannot twist before I turn. 
>  A window without glass, I am, of which you view to learn.* 
>  
>  ***What am I?***

It took me a while to finish this riddle... as well as the answer.

**Hint:**

> *If your eyes cross my back, 
>  A surprise you might lack. 
>  
>  So then what could I be? 
>  Read again and you'll see.*

---

**Edit:**

I am not a professional riddle-maker, I am just a hobbyist; i.e., my sentences might not make much sense, and in saying that, I changed the word `from` to `of` after careful studying. I mention this edit to apologise for any solvers who might not be pleased to see this change.

---

Ahh, finally I have resdiscovered the riddle that inspired me to write this one. [Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/worlds-my-first-ever-riddle?rq=1) it is! :D

Comment: the rhyme is quite nice, the riddle feels like a head scratcher ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> A book

I speak without a voice, where you can see without an eye.

> Books "speak" by being read, and the stories they contain have to be seen with the imagination, not the eye.

A heart without a beat, I hold, can make you laugh and cry.

> Not sure about the first part. For the second, an emotional story can cause the reader to laugh aloud, or cry.

I turn before I twist, but cannot twist before I turn.

> You have to turn the pages to get to the plot twist.

A window without glass, I am, from which you view to learn.

> Books are windows into imaginary universes, and some books (especially nonfiction) are useful to learn from.

--

And the hint:

> If you read the last pages of a book too soon (or sometimes even the back cover), you might see a spoiler.

And the title (Credit to Shahriar Mahmud Sajid)

> my body is pale, refers to - white pages of books,[as pale means white]
>  and share a tale, perhaps insincere; refers to- stories of fiction [as insincere means not true]

Comment: Yes! You got it! Everything is spot on! All you need to do is explain the title (which is probably obvious, now) and you are done! After that, when would you like me to give you the tick? Edit: Oh, and also, (ROT13) V hfrq gur jbeq "ivrj" orpnhfr lbhe nafjre pna or "erIVRJrq", naq rire urneq bs gur "urneg" bs gur fgbel? :D

Comment: Anyway, congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 3):

As the answer has already been found by @Tim C , I would just explain the title here to complete the answer -

> my body is pale, refers to - white pages of books,[as pale means white] 
>  and share a tale ,perhaps insincere; refers to- stories of fiction [as insincere means not true]

Comment: Correcto! DVL14 so I will upvote until then :P